# CsvHelper PrepareHeaderForMatch returns Context as one-item array

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Been using CsvHelper version 6.0.0, decided to upgrade to latest (currently 12.3.2) and found out it uses another parameter, index in lambda for `csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch`, (`Func<string,int,string>`).

The code for v6.0.0 looked like this:

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header, @"\/", string.Empty);
```

With previous line, the `IReadingContext.Record` returns an array with multiple records, one for each column.

The code for v12.3.2 looks like this:

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => Regex.Replace(header, @"\/", string.Empty);
```

But `ReadingContext.Record` now returns an array with all columns in just one record. Used the exact same file for both versions. Tried messing with  the lambda, but the outcome is the same. How can I get the columns in `Records` array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update** - This is an issue with the delimiter that has changed since version 6.0.0.  The default delimiter now uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator`.  Since I'm in the United States, my `ListSeparator` is `,` so both examples work for me.  For many countries the `ListSeparator` is `;` which is why for version 12.3.2 only 1 column was found for @dzookatz. The solution is to specify the delimiter in the configuration.

```cs
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header, @"\/", string.Empty);
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
```

---

I must be missing something. I get the same result for `var record` whether using version 6.0.0 or 12.3.2.  I'm guessing there is more going on with your data that I'm not seeing.

Version 6.0.0

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooString = $"Id,First/Name{Environment.NewLine}1,David";

        using (var reader = new StringReader(fooString))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header, @"\/", string.Empty);

            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();

            while (csv.Read())
            {
                var record = csv.Context.Record;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Version 12.3.2

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooString = $"Id,First/Name{Environment.NewLine}1,David";

        using (var reader = new StringReader(fooString))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => Regex.Replace(header, @"\/", string.Empty);

            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();

            while (csv.Read())
            {
                var record = csv.Context.Record;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I run your code, the value of `record` I get in v6.0.0 is an array of strings with 2 array members (values "1" and "David"), and in the second example, in v12.3.2 it's an array of strings containing 1 array member ("1,David"). If you see the same value for both examples it makes me wonder if it's an environment thing.

Comment: There must be something else going on, because I get 2 array members (values "1" and "David") for both.  Try adding `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";`

Comment: That worked! Still curious on why didn't your code require this line, though. Maybe this line from your comment could be added to the answer, since comments are sometimes ignored. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.  The problem is localization which must have been part of a change between 6.0.0 and now.  The default delimiter uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator`. I'm in the US so my default ListSeparator is a comma.  I'm guessing your's is likely `;`.

Comment: Correct, my default ListSeparator is `;`. In the original code there is a line `csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");`, but obviously, as you mentioned, the Delimiter has to be set, too.